# Чем отличается == от ===?

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер.Начал изучать *js*.Чем отличается `5 == 5` от `5 === 5` ?Они оба возвращают `true` . Или  `5!= 4` и `5!== 4` тоже `true`.Какой где правильнеее использовать?

Comment: === более строгое сравнение, оно так же учитывает типы данных. Оно предпочтительно в большинстве случаев.

Comment: js язык с динамическим приведением типов. `==` сравнивает приведенные значения, `===`  сравнивает с учетом типа. Т.е. `true==1` вернет `true`, а `true===1` вернет `false`

Comment: ааа поняяятно. тогда лучше про == в js забыть)

Comment: оформи как ответ

Comment: @Sultanov Shamil с тем что оно предпочтительно в большинстве случаев радикально не согласен. Как раз наоборот - гораздо чаще используется `==`

Comment: @elik `ааа поняяятно. тогда лучше про == в js забыть)` не вздумайте если хотите понятного кода, и меньше багов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**==** при сравнении выполняет приведение типов

**===** при сравнении только сравнивает не преобразуя значение одного типа к другому

Примеры:

```js
console.log(true == 1);
console.log(true === 1);
```

результатом первого выражения будет true, потому что перед сравнением производится преобразование true -> 1, а затем сравниваются 1 и 1 соовтетственно результатом будет true

результатом второго выражения будет false, потому что перед сравнением НЕ производится преобразование true -> 1, а сравниваются true и 1, соовтетственно результатом будет false, т.к. число не равно логическому значению.

Comment: _производится преобразование 1 -> true, а затем сравниваются true и true_ - не угадал. Сравниваются в итоге 1 и 1

Comment: опечатка: результатом >первого< выражения будет true и результатом >первого< выражения будет false

Comment: @Grundy  крепко ты меня поправил, спасибо